# Eclipse not recognizing class after import of jar file

Tags: java, import, reference, reference-library

I have tried creating new projects. Removing and adding the jar file. Nothing is getting this thing to recognize it. I don't know if I am adding this correctly or not. Could someone please direct me, thanks.

[image: Not recognizing Money class]

EDIT: After some research using the help from the comments, it seems the problem is that the jar file only works if I am using a default package. I obviously don't want to use the default package so how can I change the Jar to fix this?

Comment: chances of us noticing anything looking at a very small print-screen are quite thin. my advice, install maven and let that handle dependencies. Either way, you don't show any import statements, we have no idea what's in that .jar, ...

Comment: Try adding it via external Jar.

Comment: You can try removing the reference to the `jar` file, and adding the `comp121` project, go to JavaBuildPath>Projects>Add.. and add that project. Of course, you'll need to fix the comp121 project first

Comment: Your default package in `lab01.jar` is not inside `src` folder.

Comment: @Stultuske on the left it shows what is in that Jar. If you look under References Libraries, also the picture is bigger if you click on it. amal I have tried that and it doesn't work. I just tried that... and nothing but thanks I will also try moving folders entirely. Shanu I don't know how to move the classes from default to src under Referenced Library, I was under the impression Eclipse set this up on its own. I will research this thanks.

Comment: @JustinDuncan as Shanu already commented ... all code should be in the src folder. You should also never have any code in the default package.

Comment: It is because I am not using the default package in my project. Whenever I move my files to the not recommended default package they recognize the jar file. Is this normal behavior? Can I change this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a workaround or fix. I had to exclude the folders from my build path to use the jar file that had a default package. I did figure out how to deconstruct/reconstruct but for future reasons, I would not want to do this everytime someone hands me a file using the default pkg. So here is a screenshot of a working setup:
[image]

Please click it if it is not big enough for you. The summ/wint folders are excluded and I am able to use a class from the jar file without editing the jar file.

```
    Money dd = new Dollar();
```

Thanks for all the comments.